# Zener Diode Current Problem

Tags: zener

In the diagram below, ignore everything except for D<sub>z</sub> and R<sub>vdd</sub>. D<sub>z</sub>'s job is to protect the VDD pin in the event that the voltage input into that pin goes over 20V. R<sub>vdd</sub>'s job is to limit the current through D<sub>z</sub> to keep it from becoming damaged.

However, reference designs provided by the manufacturer have R<sub>vdd</sub> listed as 10 - 22Ohms, and the power dissipation of their selected D<sub>z</sub> is listed as 500mW. At 20V, D<sub>z</sub> should be dissipating way more than 500mW, right?

[image]

Comment: How much current is going through Dz, though? What's the voltage across the Na winding of that transformer?

Comment: At 20V and Rvdd = 22Ohms, we would have about 900mA being sinked by Dz. 

Edit: Unless I am missing something somewhere. Dz is supposed to protect the Vdd pin in the event that the voltage across Na exceeds 20V.

Comment: My calculations give 1.3 volts across the resistor and just 60 mA through the zener. This still gives about a watt of dissipation in the zener, but that's not going to be an average value, just peak.

Answer (score 1):

Rvdd is fed by a transformer winding and so an over voltage condition will be momentary, certainly not DC.  One might expect the voltage on Na to be equal to that on Np, which is clamped by Cin to the supply voltage, however parasitic inductance could cause Na to spike at a higher voltage but with very little energy - enough to blow out a semiconductor junction but not enough to heat a resistor significantly.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like I should just choose a resistor that can dissipate the power spike caused by the parasitic inductance. Is that correct?

Comment: I think so.  If the reference design specifies 500mW I’d be very much inclined to go with that.